# Convert Date time to specific format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert date time to specify format that is

```
Wed Aug 01 2012 14:37:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Actually i want to display the Timer using Jquery on web page. So i have tried some format i knew. And found some from http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format But none of them return the result what i require. Actually i have to pass the time from server So i have tried the following code.
**Code Behind**

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string hello = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    string hello = String.Format("{0:F}", DateTime.UtcNow);

    DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "hdrEmpty1", "show(" + hello + ")", true);
}
```

**Jquery**

```
function show(datetime) {
        alert(datetime);
        var Digital = datetime  //new Date()
        var hours = Digital.getHours()
        var minutes = Digital.getMinutes()
        var seconds = Digital.getSeconds()
        var dn = "AM"
        if (hours > 12) {
            dn = "PM"
            hours = hours - 12
        }
        if (hours == 0)
            hours = 12
        if (minutes <= 9)
            minutes = "0" + minutes
        if (seconds <= 9)
            seconds = "0" + seconds
        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + dn
        setTimeout("show()", 1000)
    }
```

Comment: I guess datetime string with GMT option is not available.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: A simple google search will give you *lots* of info about this. These examples, for instance, should get you well started: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: @Shai Please review my question i have edited it and posted what i have tried...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `date.ToString("format")` to do that. Microsoft offer a [full reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on how to format your dates the way you want.

**Edit:**

Perhaps there isn't a format ready that exactly matches your format, but you can combine your own based on the format specifiers provided in the above reference.

```
// This will output something like Wed Aug 01 2012
date.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy");
```

I believe you can follow the same pattern to complete the rest on your own.

Comment: i didnt got such type of format that returns "Wed Aug 01 2012 14:37:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: @raman I added an example for you to get you started, I believe you can follow that pattern to complete the rest on your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.Format()` and specify your own custom format - `ddd mmm dd yyyy`. Try it yourself to explore more.

Comment: i didnt got such type of format that returns "Wed Aug 01 2012 14:37:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: Is GMT +530 (India ...) is fixed or will it change according to time zone?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason with the information already provided that you can't work this out for yourself, but to get a string reading:

```
"Wed Aug 01 2012 14:37:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

Then what you want is to get the date and time in the correct form (the "Wed Aug 01 2012 14:37:50" bit) with "GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" added on the end. Assuming that that bit is always the same of course.

So the code you'd need is:

```
string string_name = (date.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "GMT+0530 \(India Standard Time\)");
//string_name will be in the form "Wed Aug 01 2012 14:37:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

But, as I said, that's something you should be able to work out yourself using the references provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to hardcode the GMT offset and cannot rely on the local time being India Standard Time you can pull this information from the `TimeZoneInfo`:

```
// get UTC from local time
var today = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
// get IST from UTC
var ist = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(today, "UTC", "India Standard Time");
// find the IST TimeZone
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
// get the UTC offset TimeSpan
var offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(today);
// determine the TimeSpan sign
var sign = offset.Ticks < 0 ? "-" : "+";
// use a custom format string
var formatted = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:ddd MMM HH:mm:ss} GMT{1}{2:hhmm}", today, sign, offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to convert datetime to indian date format in c#

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN", true);
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(txtStatus.Text, culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```